# Starting Solr in Tomcat with specifying ZK host(s)

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've setup a ZK instance and also deployed Solr in Tomcat7 on a different instance in Amazon EC2. 
Afterwards I tried starting tomcat specifying the ZK host IP, like so:

sudo service tomcat7 start -DzkHost=<< zk ip >>:2181 -DnumShards=3

Solr loads fine, but is not in the cloud.

Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the zkHost property your the solr.xml file.

For Solr 4.4 - Please see the [Solr 4.4 and beyond Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond) for further reference.
For earlier versions see the solr.xml in the example directory in the distribution (/example/solr/solr.xml)